# Maximum entropy prior for dichotomous variables

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, maximum-entropy, uninformative-prior

I have a set of dichotomous variables $A, B, C,$... and I know their probabilities $P(A), P(B), P(C),$... as well es their pairwise dependencies $P(A \cap B), P(A \cap C), P(B \cap C),$... . Or in other words, i know their variances and covariances.

However, thats the only information I have (for example, I do not know $P(A \cap B \cap C)$).

How do I find the joint distribution of those variables with the maximum entropy, given the knowledge I have?

Is this somewhere (e.g. stan) implemented?